# Please help for the moment no way to include chemistry in Mathjax

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm using the Mathjax Module on drupal 7. All working pretty good but when i'm trying to add the chemistry js, it was not the same !! I tried to enable it without success. I have read a lot of documentation, i forget where but i read : if you use "\ce", mhchem will be loaded automaticly.

Apparently it's not the case :

[image: screen capture]

My custom configuration :

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
tex2jax: {
inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)'] ],
processEscapes: true
},
showProcessingMessages: false,
messageStyle: 'none'
});
```

Tring to change

```
extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
```

to

```
extensions: ["tex2jax.js","mhchem.js"],
```

without success and a lot of other test.

No way to force the js to be loaded. May be there is a trick ?

thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the mhchem.js extension to another part of your configuration, namely the TeX part.
Here is a configuration that worked correctly for me (a modification of the 'default' custom configuration on a clean Drupal7/MathJax environment:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  extensions: ['tex2jax.js'],
  jax: ['input/TeX','output/HTML-CSS'],
  TeX: {
    extensions: ['mhchem.js'],
  },
  tex2jax: {
    inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)'] ],
    processEscapes: true,
    processClass: 'tex2jax',
    ignoreClass: 'html'
  },
  showProcessingMessages: false,
  messageStyle: 'none'
});
```

My content looked like this:

```
$2 + 2 = 4$

$\ce{H2O}$
```

and gave me this as an output:

[image]
Hope this helps!